# strptime mid-point in R

Tags: r, time, strptime

I have two vectors of start and end point time/date data in a dataframe, formatted using `strptime()`.

I am able to use `difftime()` to return a vector of differences in any number of units, e.g. hours, minutes, etc., but is there a way to obtain a vector of mid-point times in the same format as the start and end point times?

Comment: Please consider adding example data + what you tried + the expected output to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
time <- Sys.time()
df <- data.frame(as.list(c(start=time, end=time+2)))
df$mid <- df$end + ((df$start-df$end) / 2)
df
#                 start                 end                 mid
# 1 2016-03-16 15:09:59 2016-03-16 15:10:01 2016-03-16 15:10:00
```